# como validar que los datos ingresados por un usuario sean del tipo String en java

Tags: java, string, input

** //Debería hacer un método así pero que controle textos y que no se ingresen cadenas vacías solamente**

```
  public static int demanaEnter(String mensaje) {
        Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
        int value;
        boolean valueOk = false;
        //int minValor=0;
        do {
            System.out.println(mensaje + "\n");
            valueOk = in.hasNextInt();
            if (!valueOk) {
                in.next();
                System.out.println("Debes ingresar un entero");
            }
        } while (!valueOk);
        value = in.nextInt();
        in.nextLine();

        return value;

    }
```

Sería un metodo que pudiera reutilizar en diferentes proyectos

Comment: Que es lo que quieres?, deseas saber si lo ingresado es un texto o si es un numero?, por favor añade una mejor explicación

Answer (score 0):

A ver si te sirve

Se trata de introducir un texto y evaluar carácter a carácter, para ello por medio de un bucle, una vez pasada la cadena introducida por teclado a "char", va comprobando si es vocal o consonante, vocal acentuada, espacio o signo de puntuación.

Está estructurado de tal forma que puedes agregar o quitar lo que no deseas evaluar, y también puedes quitar el que vaya imprimiendo lo que es cada carácter y te haga una evaluación general de todo el texto

El método lo puedes llevar a una clase independiente y llamar desde cualquier otro método como se hace aquí llamándolo desde el método main

```
public class EvaluarLetras 
{
    public static void main(String[] args) 
    {
        Scanner teclado = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Introduzca un texto por favor: ");
        String texto = teclado.nextLine();
        int contador = texto.length();

        boolean rLetra = evaluaLetra(texto);

        if (rLetra == true){
            System.out.println("El texto está formado por letras, espacios o signos de puntuación");
        }
        else{
            System.out.println("En el texto no solo hay letras");
        }
}

static boolean evaluaLetra(String texto)
{
    boolean resultado = false;
    for (int x = 0; x < texto.length(); x++) {
        char c = texto.charAt(x);

        if ((c >= 'a' && c <= 'z') || (c >= 'A' && c <= 'Z')) {
            resultado = true;
            System.out.println("El carácter es vocal o consoante no acentuado");
        }
            else if ((c == 'á') || (c == 'é') || (c == 'í') || (c == 'ó') || (c == 'ú')) {
                resultado = true;
                System.out.println("El carácter es vocal acentuada");
            }
                else if ((c == 'Á') || (c == 'É') || (c == 'Í') || (c == 'Ó') || (c == 'Ú')) {
                    resultado = true;
                    System.out.println("El carácter es vocal acentuada");
                }
                    else if (c == ' ') {
                        resultado = true;
                        System.out.println("El carácter es un espacio");
                    }
                        else if ((c == ',') || (c == ':') || (c == ';')) {
                            resultado = true;
                            System.out.println("El carácter es un signo de puntuación");
                        }
                            else{
                                resultado = false;
                                System.out.println("El carácter es un número o símbolo no reconocido");
                            }
        }
        return resultado;
    }
}
```

Comment: no creo que sea la mejor respuesta al problema, pues solo se quiere verificar si el dato ingresado es de tipo string

Comment: Vaya Chistian, pues entonces lo he entendido yo mal, pensé que con string se refería a texto y no a números, ya que en su método evaluaba números. En todo caso, sin problema, si dice que no es lo que busca, elimino mi respueta. Muchas gracias Christian.

Comment: Es una buena solucion pero no a este problema, creo que es facil de resolver, te invito a que pienses un poco y elabores una respuesta a este problema, no he programado en java hace mucho tiempo por lo que prefiero no publicar nada :)

Comment: Es que sigo entonces sin entender muy bien lo que pide

Comment: me acabo de dar cuenta que hay contradicciones en su pregunta, pero creo que se refiere a tener que evaluar si lo que ingreso el usuario es un numero y que tampoco sea vacio (`""`), en todo caso no entiendas puedes dejarle un comentario diciendo que explique mejor su problema.